# UDP transmitter down with 5370sta wifi driver

Tags: udp, wifi, driver

I am using an embedded linux kernel 2.6 onto an Intel Atom CPU. Due to the slow performance of the 2x00usb wifi driver, I decide replace it by the 5370sta. Now speed connection is up to 10 times faster but I am experimented a problem with UDP transmission that worked like a charm with the 2800usb wireless driver.

The UDP connection can receive all datagrams properly, but the transmission turn down after some minutes. It is curious because while transmitter is down, the receiver keeps receiving correctly. After some minutes, the UDP transmitter comes alive again. I have not been able to find a pattern, the failure is apparently random, but I am sure that there is a reason, maybe a buffer saturation or something like that.

I have modified the socket bind from (ip=0.0.0.0 to my CPU ip) and the broadcast (from 255.255.255.255 to 192.168.0.255) among several non successful attempts. But I thing that problem is with the new wifi driver and some configuration that I don't know.